# I got this error while running my express app

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, macos, aerospike

Error: dlopen(/Users/mylaptop/Documents/login-service/api/loginservice/node_modules/aerospike/build/Release/aerospike.node, 0x0001): symbol not found in flat namespace (_FIPS_mode_set)
undefined

I am using macbook air with intel chip and try to run my project but got this error message please help me out how do i solve this problem.

"aerospike": "^3.11.7"

Comment: What version of macOS are you using?  What version of OpenSSL do you have installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this issue by downgrade my node version.